# How to get data from modal window to main window in node js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am developing an application in nodejs with express and mysql. In one of the form I have to search product. For searching I had opened a modal window (by clicking a button in main window) which contains a datatable control. after searching user clicks on the product in modal window. On clicking the modal window should get closed and the productid should get fetched into main window productid textbox.

I have tried by including iframe inside a div of modal window. But could not find a way to fetch the productid into main window.

Comment: Hi, Raj, I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do. I had a similar problem and worked out how to get the data in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jessachandler/pen/BGwWLB) Essentially, if the modal is on the same page, you can access its elements with js on that page and get the data into a list (locally or through your backend)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by

```
parent.document.getElementById('parenttextboxid')=productid;
this.window.close();
```

I had this solution. But what if I don't want to use an iframe. How to implement that is nodejs.